# How can I display the text html code as unformatted text using a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using basic Javascript and HTML and this is the output that I'm trying to achieve:

```
1
2
3

innerHTML = 1 textContent= 1
innerHTML = <p> 2 </p> textContent= 2
innerHTML = 3 textContent= 3
```

and this is the code that I have currently

```
<html>

<div id="txt">
 <div id="txt1"> 1 </div>
 <div id="txt2">
 <p> 2 </p>
 </div>
 <div id="txt3"> 3 </div>
</div>
<div id="innerHTMLtxt"></div>

// replaces all of the html elemnets with versions that won't change the display
<script>
function escapeHTML(html) { return
 html.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}

//loops through the
for (i=1;i<4;i++){
 var x="txt"+i;
 var h = document.getElementById(x).innerHTML;
 h = escapeHTML(h);
 var t = document.getElementById(x).textContent;
 document.write("<p>innerHTML = " + h + " textContent= " + t +"</p>");
 }
</script>

</html>
```

there is something wrong with the function escapeHTML because it does not display anything, only the word undefined

```
1
2

3
// replaces all of the html elemnets with versions that won't change the display
innerHTML = undefined textContent= 1

innerHTML = undefined textContent= 2

innerHTML = undefined textContent= 3
```

If I comment out the escapeHTML function, it will display the innerHTML with the p tags acting as a new line instead of printing them which is what I want.
If anyone could help as to why the escapeHTML does not work in replacing the html elements with a text friendly version it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to return the value in the function `escapeHTML()`, so `h` is undefined.

Comment: thanks, such a simple problem but I didn't notice it

Comment: Remember that in JS, `return` can't go on a line by itself, because the parser takes it as returning nothing, which is the same as returning `undefined`.